# Setup Intel One API framework on MacOS - how to decrease the loading time of conda when I do "source /opt/intel/oneapi/setvars.sh"

Tags: python, terminal, conda, zsh, intel

I am on MacOS 11.3 Big Sur and I use the framework OneAPI from Intel.

To load all the environment variables, I put into my `~/.zshrc` :

```
source /opt/intel/oneapi/setvars.sh
```

Before I used Conda of OneAPI, the time for launching a new Terminal and get the prompt was acceptable (2-3 seconds).

But since I use Conda of OneAPI, it takes a time very long to launch and get the prompt (at least 10 seconds): it is very annoying.

I tried to use a config file for `setvars.sh` sourcing:

```
source /opt/intel/oneapi/setvars.sh --config="/opt/intel/oneapi/config_setvars.txt" > /dev/null
```

with `config_setvars.txt`:

```
default=exclude
mkl=latest
idp=latest
```

But it takes still too much time (~ 8 seconds) to get the prompt of a launched terminal.

Is there a way to activate `conda` (and environment variables associated) with the file sourced `setvars.sh` or by modifying `config_setvars.txt` ?

Indeed, to know if `conda` is activated or not, I did a simple shell function:

```
function isconda() {
 answer=$(echo $CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV)
 if [ -z "$answer" ];
   then print "NO CONDA ACTIVATED"
   else
   print "YES CONDA ACTIVATED"
 fi
}
```

I do not have `anaconda` or `miniconda` and I wouldn't like to install them.

Here is my `~/.condarc`:

```
auto_activate_base: false
auto_update_conda: false
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/intel/osx-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/jdblischak/osx-64
  - defaults
channel_priority: flexible
```

I suspect that sourcing `/opt/intel/oneapi/setvars.sh` calls all the environments, especially `conda` and that's why it takes a long time to load everything: how to prevent to load all these environments ?

I don't know what to do now, how can I get the prompt more quickly when I launch a new terminal on iTerm2?

### Update

(1) I realize that since I am using Conda from Intel OneAPI, I have no more `python Intel`:

```
$ python
Python 3.7.10 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Feb 19 2021, 15:59:12)
[Clang 11.0.1 ] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(.startup.py)
```

Is it normal?

(2) when I do a `ls` command into `ls /opt/intel/oneapi/intelpython/python3.7` , I get a bunch of files:

```
extract_packages_ipy.sh
condainstall.py
ReleaseNotes.txt
setup_scripts
generate_urlstxt.sh
shell
envs
libexec
etc
var
fonts
man
sbin
share
env
licensing
include
sys_check
lib
ssl
pkgs
bin
conda-meta
condabin
```

Does this bunch of files cause the long time to load all intelpython libraries located in `/opt/intel/oneapi/intelpython/python3.7`?

Indeed, when I perform the sourcing of setvars.sh, the largest elapsed time is taken at the level of intelpython library, so I wonder if my issue could come from this.

Moreover, sourcing the following file takes a long time :

```
source /opt/intel/oneapi/intelpython/python3.7/env/vars.sh
```

Is there a relation?

Comment: I guess you don't need env activated in all the terminals; if so, you can put it in a separate script, which you can call when needed.

Comment: @kHarshit . Isn't there a way to load only important variables environment of `conda ` with the sourced file `/opt/intel/oneapi/setvars.sh` ? how to deal with ?